# Is there a structure that provides BOTH energy AND metal in the base game for Total Annihilation?

Tags: total-annihilation

The question itself is pretty straight-forward. I'm looking for a single, stand-alone structure (as opposed to a pair of structures) that provides both energy and metal simultaneously instead of only one or the other. However, I do not recall the name of the structure and have been up and down websites and search engines looking for this, having turned up nothing, and at this point I'm pretty sure I won't find it unless I can somehow get the name of it and search that way.

### Does the plant actually exist?

As far as I recall, yes. I grew up playing the game with my father, and this particular structure was a favorite, when we managed to get it built. He had backed up a couple hundred files (maps, units, and more) on floppy disks. Unfortunately, we are no longer in possession of the floppy disk collection (water damage ruined them during a flood) and he doesn't remember the name of the plant either.

### What does it look like?

Descriptively, it looks something like a set of Core Fusion Power Plants interconnected with some manner of piping, and the size of the structure is larger than the Core Advanced Vehicle Plant. It takes enormous amounts of energy and metal to construct, but once built it manages to supply the continuous building of a small army without any hiccups.

### Research

I didn't catalog everything as I searched (as I was expecting to find this thing quickly), but what I remember searching for sure is listed below.

*Note: Since structures are also included when the game calculates for "Unit Max", I searched for this power plant also within "units" categories.*

Websites I have searched include:

- [Total Annihilation Universe > Units](https://units.tauniverse.com/?p=all)
- [Total Annihilation Universe > Unit Guide](https://www.tauniverse.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33452)
- [Total Annihilation Universe > Hydration Plant](https://www.tauniverse.com/forum/showthread.php?t=6379)
- [Strategy Wiki > Total Annihilation > Units](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Total_Annihilation/Units)
- [Strategy Wiki > Total Annihilation > Structures](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Total_Annihilation/Structures)
- [Fandom > Total Annihilation > Units](https://totalannihilation.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Total_Annihilation_Units)
- [Fandom > Total Annihilation > Structure](https://totalannihilation.fandom.com/wiki/Structure)
- [GameFAQ > Total Annihilation > FAQ/Strategy Guide](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/43335-total-annihilation/faqs/2260)

Google searches have included the game name "Total Annihilation", the abbreviated "TA", "energy and metal", "power plant", "metal plant", "production center", and so on.

Edit Explanations:

- User [Frank](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/20456/frank) pointed out to me that my initial question was, if not extremely close to, a game-identification request. Upon reviewing the guidelines, I concur--my initial question was based on memory, which is not an acceptable basis for posting.
- User [mmatthews](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/73786/mmatthews) pointed out that the Steam and GoG releases of TA include all official expansions. By implication, this would mean that if the structure I recalled was in the base game, then I would be able to eventually find it through normal gameplay, as I have the Steam release. Said structure is not among the base game's build options.

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a game identification, even if it's limited to a single game.  Are you sure it existed in the base game, and not a mod?

Comment: As a note, TA is available on Steam and GoG, (includes expansions).  I do not believe one structure to produce both metal and energy ever existed in TA without mods.

Comment: There's an experimental building in *Supreme Commander* that can be built that generates energy and mass (and quite a lot of it as well). Searching around and going back on memory, that's the only example I can find that's close.

Comment: Thank you Frank for calling out the game-ID issue! At this point I think I was remembering incorrectly--it was probably a mod. Thank you mmatthews for pointing out that Steam and GoG included all expansions with their releases!

Comment: I'm glad you found what you were looking for!  I'm going to close this with our game identification reason, as it is the same sort of issue, with the same problems.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Would it work better if I just delete the question? Or is it best to leave it in place and wait for closing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No, within the *base game* there is not a structure that provides *both* resources by itself.

The closest thing I have found so far is part of the Escalation expansion hosted by Total Annihilation Universe: the **Core Vault** (image below). However, this structure was specifically introduced in the 7.0 Beta of Escalation in April 2014 (see [this](https://www.tauniverse.com/forum/showthread.php?s=&threadid=44024) thread), which succeeds the recalled experiences by nearly a decade.

[image]

More information about the Core Vault can be found [here](https://taesc.tauniverse.com/unitguide/unit_CORVAULT.html).